# No Albums._ID in Android Q

Tags: android, mediastore

My code query album info with below columns from from Uri MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.getContentUri("external", id).

```
String[] cols = new String[] {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS_FOR_ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART
            };
```

Running with device below Android Q, it works. With Android Q, it will crash. It seems there is no column _id for album in Android Q.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _id
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:951)
How do I solve this issue? As my app using CursorWrapper, it reply on _id column, without this app will crash with another issue.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Because MyCursorHelper read _id column, if no such value provided, it will init mRowIDColumn with -1. Then getLong will crash with column -1.

```
mRowIDColumn = cursorPresent ? cursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;

long getId(int position) {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As my app reply on this CursorWrapper, I don't know how to replace it with other approach. Maybe get an workaround for column _id is an easier way?

Comment: Column .ALBUM_ID?

Comment: Change to ALBUM_ID can avoid "Invalid column _id" error. But as I mentioned, MyCursorHelper  will check _id, without it, it will crash with another error.